# How can I convert Tensor to eagerTensor

Tags: numpy, tensorflow2.0, tensor

I got tensor class from `Model.pred()` that tensor class is `<tf.python.framework.ops.Tensor>` (not eager).

but I can't use them for custom loss function. So I tried convert 'that Tensor' to `<tf.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor>`.

If I convert them I can use `.numpy()` for a calculate in loss function.

Is there way to convert them?
or Can I get numpy in `<... ops.Tensor>`?

I'm using Tensorflow 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. Try forcing eager execution with `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` or `tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()` at the start of your code.
2. Or using a session ([documentation here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/Session)) and calling `.eval()` on your Tensor instead of `.numpy()`.

Example code of the second possibility:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
# Build a graph.
a = tf.constant(5.0)
b = tf.constant(6.0)
c = a * b

# Launch the graph in a session.
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()

with sess.as_default():
  print(c.eval())

sess.close()
```